# Openlayers map jitters on dynamic centering of feature movement animation

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I want to make "camera follow" effect on feature while its moves along path.
The feature is moved using `requestAnimationFrame`, here is the example code:

```
var lastFrame = +new Date;
var updateSlider = function () {
    var now = +new Date, deltaTime = now - lastFrame;
    trackValue += deltaTime;
    self.move(trackValue);
    lastFrame = now;
    self.Timer = requestAnimationFrame(updateSlider);
};
updateSlider();

.move = function (timestamp) {
 var point = LineString.getCoordinateAtM(timestamp);
 if(point) Feature.setCoordinate(point);
 this.followCamera();
};
```

I tried a few options of centering the view. And it works, but the problem is that the map jitters. Need help on getting rid of the jitter.

See this OL example - http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/geolocation-orientation.html, to see map jitters, press "Simulate"

```
.followCamera = function() {
 var extent = Feature.getGeometry().getExtent();
 A) view.set('center', ol.extent.getCenter(extent);
 B) view.setCenter(ol.extent.getCenter(extent); 
 C) view.animate({center: ol.extent.getCenter(extent)});
 D) view.fit(extent) <- Not usable in my case, because i want to zoom in/out manually
};
```

Also you can try this example (taken from ol examples) - https://jsfiddle.net/32z45kLo/5/ - try with and without `setCenter` part at `moveFeature` function (`line 152`)

Here is the video - https://youtu.be/L96HgWZi6Lo

Comment: I think it depends of the specs of the client machine because for me there is no jitters, that's look fluid enough

Comment: hmm, interesting, can you please tell me your specs? i'm currently running on i3, intel hd graphics 4600 with 512 mb and 16 gb RAM

Comment: Ok after looking more carefully I think I see what you are talking about... it's more the pinpoint that jitter right? Maybe something is debounced in the code? Here i7, integrated 1gb hd graphics, 16gb ram

Comment: Map rotation, is really fluid for me, when the pinpoint is not moving,

Comment: yes, map jitters a little bit less than a pinpoint but it does. can be seen at the edge of the screen.
it's not about specs i guess.
When its animated without centering it's smooth

Comment: rotation is fuild, you are right. my guess is that its because of the sometimes centering is happens faster then point move and vice versa

Comment: Maybe it's related with this line https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/src/ol/View.js#L1158

Comment: yeah i thought that too, but `view.set('center', ol.extent.getCenter(extent));` gives same effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167096/discussion-between-below-the-radar-and-manchary-manchaary).

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you are creating and drawing a new feature to `vectorContext` at each frame animation.

Instead you should create a feature and add it into a `vectorLayer` once, and then modify its geometry at each frame animation.

```
  //here you define the pinpoint feature and add it to the vectorLayer
  var feature = new ol.Feature();
  feature.setStyle(styles.geoMarker);
  vectorLayer.getSource().addFeature(feature);

  var moveFeature = function(event) {
    var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
    var frameState = event.frameState;

    if (animating) {
      var elapsedTime = frameState.time - now;
      // here the trick to increase speed is to jump some indexes
      // on lineString coordinates
      var index = Math.round(speed * elapsedTime / 1000);

      if (index >= routeLength) {
        stopAnimation(true);
        return;
      }

      var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(routeCoords[index]);
      //here you modify the feature geometry instead of creating a new feature
      feature.setGeometry(currentPoint);
      map.getView().setCenter(routeCoords[index]);
    }
    // tell OpenLayers to continue the postcompose animation
    map.render();
  };
```

working demo without jitter:
https://jsfiddle.net/32z45kLo/80/

Comment: hmm...in my app i reuse same features (not creating a new one), But maybe creating new `geometry` will do the trick, i will try it tomorrow

Comment: creaing new geometry didn't help, also it drops fps

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that points on the lines are not equidistant thus the position jump from one to another but nothing inbeetween.

Look at this example to calculate points on the line: http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.featureanimation.path.html

Using a [ol.featureAnimation.Path](https://github.com/Viglino/ol-ext/blob/master/src/featureanimation/Path.js), if you have to move the map on position change, just listen to the change event on the animated feature to get its current position:

```
geoMarker.on('change', function() {
  map.getView().setCenter(geoMarker.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
});
```

You can see a working example with your code here: https://jsfiddle.net/Viglino/nhrwynzs/

Comment: q1 - do i need to create `animationFeature.Path` for each `feature` ? If i wan't to animate multiple `features` (e.g 31)

q2 - is it possible to `resume` the `playback` without slicing coordinates array from the point i paused (`route`)

p.s: the animation is really smooth with your extension

Comment: You have to create an animation for every feature you want to animate (the animation may be different for each one).

Comment: ok, got it, i will try. p.s: thanks for making this great extension!:)

Comment: There is no pause just start / stop / isPlaying

Comment: Look at the http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/animation/map.featureanimation.path.html. By clicking on the animate button you can animate more than one feature along the path.

Comment: If you're looking at more functionalities look at this example https://viglino.github.io/ol3-games/examples/map.sprite.path.html

Comment: i made a video of my problem - https://youtu.be/L96HgWZi6Lo (sorry for the quality, but you can see the problem with `jitter`